# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘__extension__’ in Linux (Cent OS)

Tags: c++, linux

My code is below,

```
namespace A
{
     namespace B
     {
           unsigned int htonl(unsigned int address)
           {
                return 0;
           }
     }
}
```

Now I know that `htonl` is a library function in Linux. Even though I am defining it under namespaces it produces the mentioned error. How can I fix it without changing the function signature?

Comment: It could be that `htnol()` is a macro. You should study the output of the preprocessor, and (of course) remove the relevant `#include`(s) which I assume you omitted from the question. Also I re-tagged it as C++ since `namespace` is not C.

Comment: Isn't there any other way around? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `htonl`, in Linux at least, is a (sometimes) macro that expands to `__bswap32`, which in turn is a rather long macro (which has `__attribute__((extension))` as part of it). Macros do not "care" about namespaces.

If you REALLY want your own function that is called `htonl` (you probably do not, in general - call it something else), then you can do

```
#ifdef htonl
#undef htonl
#endif
```

The `#ifdef` is there to avoid undefining something that isn't a macro.

Or you could figure out which header file it is that produces `htonl` (`<arpa/inet.h>` in my Linux installation) and not include that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's probably worth noting that the library function `htonl` takes, and returns, a `uint32_t`. Secondly, as one of the commenters notes, it's a macro, at least on Linux, and is defined as `__bswap_32(x)` in `netinet/in.h`.

So your options are limited to ways to avoid the preprocessor substituting the macro expansion before compilation:

a) Rename the function.

b) Avoid the include file. Either moving it after the function definition, or removing it entirely. Note that you'll need to then call this function with a namespace qualification, for example `A::B::htonl`, or the preprocessor will substitute it there as well.

c) Undefine the macro. This will be problematic if you later want the original definition restored, though.

Answer (score -1):

Use ::htons call - add "::" before api name.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.